# How to write a print function for a binary tree in C

Tags: c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
    
struct Node {
  int data;
  struct Node *rightchild;
  struct Node *leftchild;
};
    
struct Node *Create(struct Node *root, int data);
struct Node *Insert(struct Node *root, int data);
void Print(struct Node *root);

void main() {
  struct Node *root;
  root = Create(root, 10);
  root = Insert(root, 20);
  root = Insert(root, 30);

  Print(root);
}
    
struct Node *Create(struct Node *root, int data) {
  root = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
  root->data = data;
  root->leftchild = NULL;
  root->rightchild = NULL;

  return root;
}
    
struct Node *Insert(struct Node *root, int data) {
  if (root->leftchild == NULL) {
    root->leftchild = Create(root->leftchild,data);
  }
  else if (root->rightchild == NULL) {
    root->rightchild = Create(root->rightchild,data);
  }
  return root;
}
    
void Print(struct Node *root) {}
}
```

I wrote this code to create a tree and insert some elements into the tree. If the steps are correct, how can I write a print function for this program? The main thing that I want to do is create a function which will find the height of the tree but before that, I tried to create the tree itself and print the elements.

Comment: Your insertion code is not correct. It's not referring to a comparator to make a decision to go left or right. [Tree traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) is the term you should use when discussing printing elements.

Comment: You can travese a binary tree in multiple ways, three of them being pre-order, in-order and post-order. Which order would you like the elements to be printed?

Comment: Well, after posting it I realised my mistake as well. Must we make the user enter the right child if they enter the left child and vice versa?

Comment: No. You almost never force a user to enter the data in a specific order. Your code has to be [robust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_(computer_science)#:~:text=Robust%20programming%20is%20a%20style,accurate%20and%20unambiguous%20error%20messages.) enough to handle user-entered data or program-to-program data. The concepts of tree traversal will assist you in correcting your insertion code.

Comment: Then for each entrance, I need to check it and then insert it into the next position which won't break the rule of a binary tree?

Comment: Yes, you can consider passing a comparator function to the insertion code or you can define a Tree structure to hold the root plus a function for callbacks like: compare, insert, delete. Then you can pass the Tree to a generic "insert into any tree" function.